# Is it OK to upload thesis including published work to personal website?

Tags: thesis, copyright

I think the question is simple, but answers may be quite different - I fear.

I have recently written my Thesis, which also includes some peer-reviewed published papers. As a general rule, is it ok to post the .pdf of my Thesis on my personal website?

If it depends on the journal and University where the papers have been sent to, what right should I be looking for on the journals website?

Comment: The first place you might want to look is probably the copyright transfer agreements you signed when you published your papers, not their websites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Sherpa/Romeo database (http://www.sherpa.ac.uk/romeo/) will give you all the information about journal policies concerning self-archiving.